# How do I remove a GIT remote that has a "blank" name?

Tags: git, github, tortoisegit

Somehow during my SSH configuration (for GitHub), Tortoise Git has created a remote configuration with a "blank" name.

Neither Tortoise nor Git command line will allow me to remove it because Git requires a name to be passed for the remote configuration.

Has anyone run into this before and what is the solution?

[image: Tortoise GIT remote issue]

**Update**

Below is the screenshot showing the section I removed based on the answer.  The file is: `./.git/config`

[image: GIT config file]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use a text editor to manually edit `.git/config` file in your repo and rename the remote there.

Comment: I was actually able to remove the whole definition and everything is working great.  Thanks for the advice.  I'll upload a screenshot of the config for others to reference.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can remove it from github:

```
https://github.com/blog/1377-create-and-delete-branches
```

on your repo:

```
https://github.com/<user>/<repo>/branches
```

Comment: Read the question carefully - OP is trying to modify the _local_ repo. Also _remotes_ != _branches_.